# C# Abstract Class Implementation

Tags: c#, abstract-class, abstract

I am just starting to use abstract classes and would like to know if I am using them in the correct manner. In my example I have a Windows Form application where Form1 is the main UI for the app. Within Form1 I have a method which writes debug messages to a richtextbox. I currently have a bunch of different classes which all have the same method in them to write message back to the main UI richtextbox. However, I was wondering if it would make sense to make this functionality part of an abstract class, an just have all of my other class inherit this functionality as shown below?

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace abstractTest
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Main User Interface
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public void RTBWriteLine(string message)
        {
            /* Print (append) message to the debug richtextbox */
            this.richTextBox1.AppendText(message + Environment.NewLine);

            /* Select the last entered message */
            this.richTextBox1.Select(richTextBox1.Text.Length, 0);

            /* Scroll to selected message */
            this.richTextBox1.ScrollToCaret();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Class1 c1 = new Class1(this);
            Class2 c2 = new Class2(this);
        }
    }

    public abstract class absTest
    {
        protected Form1 MainUI;

        public virtual void MainRTBWriteLine(string msg)
        {
            if (MainUI != null)
            {
                MainUI.RTBWriteLine(msg);
            }
        }
    }

    public class Class1 : absTest
    {
        public Class1(Form callingForm)
        {
            MainUI = callingForm as Form1;
            MainRTBWriteLine("This is Class1");
        }
    }

    public class Class2 : absTest
    {
        public Class2(Form callingForm)
        {
            MainUI = callingForm as Form1;
            MainRTBWriteLine("This is Class2");
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
My main goal is that I would to make DTBWriteLine(among many other methods that update the main UI is some way) to be available to all of my classes, but only have the code in one location. Right now, I have the following method (among many others) duplicated in every class I've created:

```
public virtual void MainRTBWriteLine(string msg)
{
    if (MainUI != null)
    {
        MainUI.RTBWriteLine(msg);
    }
}
```

If putting this in an abstract class isn't the best approach, what is?

Comment: FYI: `absTest` doesn't follow the C# naming convention. You should use `AbsTest` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this scenario is a perfect example for using an abstract class.

When you have shared functionality in an inheritance tree.

Answer (score 1):

An abstract class is one option in this situation, yes. An alternative (particularly if you want to reuse the same functionality from elsewhere) would be to create a utility method in a separate class. Inheritance is one way of achieving code reuse, but it's not always the best choice - consider the options carefully.

Answer (score 1):

To me it seems that what you are after is a separate DebugLogger class whose only concern would be logging debug messages to the textbox.

Then your other classes would just delegate debug logging to this one class rather than inheriting this additional functionality that has not much to do with their primary function.

Comment: +1 for "has not much to do with their primary function" - the delegation approach provides better separation of concerns here.

Comment: In the example above I only show a method for writing debug messages, however in my actual application I also have methods in place for updating/incrementing a progress bar and updating statusStrip labels to which I would like to make available to multiple classes.

Comment: If the delegation approach is more suitable, can you please provide an example of how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The point of an abstract class, according to the docs:

> Use the abstract modifier in a class declaration to indicate that a
>   class is intended only to be a base class of other classes
>
> - An abstract class cannot be instantiated.
> - An abstract class may contain abstract methods and accessors.
> - It is not possible to modify an abstract class with the sealed modifier, which means that the class cannot be inherited.
> - A non-abstract class derived from an abstract class must include actual implementations of all inherited abstract methods and
>     accessors.

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense and reflects the idea with abstract classes. In your examples it also provides you with a nice separation of concerns where your absTest implementations enables you to swap logging strategies at a single point if needed.

Answer (score 0):

Abstract classes are widely used to implement [Template Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) pattern. Check [C# implementation samples](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternTemplate.aspx).

I would add that in your example is not nessesary to use exactly `abstract` keyword. `absTest` may be not `abstract` without any harm, and it would be fully functional in case of `absTest(Form callingForm)` constructor implementation.